# How can we stop publishing of a structure group with help eventing?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I want to stop publishing of structure group with the help of eventing? Please share some code.

Comment: Sorry Alok, but I downvoted this question. There are many examples of (and tutorials on) event systems out there already, yet you fail to include what you have already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I was away from Stack for sometime so was not able to update

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to stop users publishing Structure Groups (or Publications) from the GUI then maybe you could use a GUI extension. Jaime Santos has a great post on Hiding commands in the GUI:

http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/2011/10/2011-sdl-tridion-gui-extensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest that you open the Structure Group properties page, and just un-check the "Publishable" check box? Or is there another reason you want to achieve this with an event?

Answer (score 0):

You really need to elaborate your questions. I don't know what exactly you want to do, but I suspect that you want to remove the possibility to publish entire structure groups?

If you want to remove items to be published you need to write a Structure Group Resolver that does this for you.

When you elaborated your question I can share some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

We have done this by using GUI extensions.